# Could not instantiate class from tuple

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables `Setup` and `Product` and I created a `SetupProductJoin` to represent a model when both tables are joined. `productName` is a String (varchar) from the `Product` table but I am getting an error

The error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not instantiate class [com.nano.comp.domain.io.SetupProductJoin] from tuple; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not instantiate class [com.nano.comp.domain.io.SetupProductJoin] from tuple
```

```
public interface SetupProductJoinInterface {

    String getProductName();
}
```

```
public abstract class SetupProductJoin implements SetupProductJoinInterface {
    
    private String productName = "";

    public SetupProductJoin() {

    }

    public SetupProductJoin(String productName) {
        super();
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getproductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setproductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Query(value = " SELECT new com.nano.comp.domain.io.SetupProductJoin(p.name as productName) " +
        " FROM Setup bs " +
        "   INNER JOIN Product p ON p.id = bs.productId " +
        " WHERE bs.wgId = ?1 "
)
List<SetupProductJoin> findByWgId(Long wgId);
```

Controller

```
List<SetupProductJoin> setup = setupRepository.findByWgId(wgId);
```

Comment: How should hibernate instantiate an `abstract` class? Your `SetupProductJoin` is `abstract` you simply cannot instantiate an `abstract` class.

Comment: Nice catch @M.Deinum.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @M. Deinum, `SetupProductJoin` should not be abstract.

Your query seems wrong. Try below query:

```
@Query(value = " SELECT new com.nano.comp.domain.io.SetupProductJoin(p.name) " +
    " FROM Setup bs " +
    "   INNER JOIN Product p ON p.id = bs.productId " +
    " WHERE bs.wgId = :wgId "
)
List<SetupProductJoin> findByWgId(@Param("wgId") Long wgId);
```

Also check your getter/setter method names, they should be in camelcase.

```
public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}
```